# How to delete user with confirmation by passing url and username var in django

Tags: django

i have html that show the list of user created in this application in table
here's the html

```
<div class="row mt">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="content-panel align-content-center">
              <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> User</th>
                    <th><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> Email</th>
                    <th><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> Division</th>
                    <th><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> Role</th>
                    <!-- <th><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i> Status</th> -->
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>  
                  {% for user in users %}
                    <tr>
                      <td class="user_name">

                        {{user.name}}

                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {{user.email}}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {{user.division}}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                      <select id="userroles" class="roleselect" data-username="{{ user.name }}">                        
                        <option selected="selected">
                          {{user.role}}
                        </option>
                        {% if user.role == "Business Analyst" %}
                           <option>Admin</option>
                           <option>Manager</option>
                           <option>Segment Manager</option>
                        {% elif user.role == "Admin" %}
                           <option>Business Analyst</option>
                           <option>Manager</option>
                           <option>Segment Manager</option>
                        {% elif user.role == "Manager" %}
                           <option>Admin</option>
                           <option>Business Analyst</option>
                           <option>Segment Manager</option>
                        {% else %}
                           <option>Admin</option>
                           <option>Manager</option>
                           <option>Business Analyst</option>                       
                        {% endif %}
                      </select>
                      </div>
                      </td>                    
                    <td>                  
                       <button  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}   

                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /content-panel -->
          </div>
          <!-- /col-md-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /row -->
      </section>
    </section>
```

i want to make a delete function that need a confirmation , before that i use the onlick =  "window.location.href ='{% url 'polls:deleteuser' user_name=user.name %}';", and it works but now i want to make a confirmation , so i write a script like this

```
 <script>

function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  if (confirm("Do you want to delete!")) {
   window.location.href ='{% url 'polls:deleteuser' user_name=user.name %}';
  } else {
  //don't do anything
  }

}
  </script>
```

everytime i press ok it will error `Reverse for 'deleteuser' with keyword arguments '{'user_name': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['deleteuseradmin/(?P<user_name>[^/]+)$']`

the window.location.href not working , maybe it cannot pass from the class value? i need help to fix it

here's the url

```
path('deleteuseradmin/<str:user_name>',views.del_user,name='deleteuser'),
```

thankyou

EDIT:
VIEWS.PY

```
def del_user(request, user_name): 
    u = User.objects.get(username = user_name)      
    identity = u.id
    import cx_Oracle
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('', '', sid='') 
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'', password='', dsn=dsn_tns) 
    c = conn.cursor() 
    c.execute("delete from polls_userprofileinfo where user_id = '"+str(identity)+"'")
    conn.commit()
    c.execute("delete from auth_user where  id = '"+str(identity)+"'")
    conn.commit()
    messages.success(request, "The user is deleted")     
    print("sukses");
    return redirect('/manageuser/')
```

error trace

```
NoReverseMatch at /manageuser/
Reverse for 'deleteuser' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['deleteuseradmin/(?P<user_name>[^/]+)$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/manageuser/
Django Version: 2.2.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'deleteuser' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['deleteuseradmin/(?P<user_name>[^/]+)$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 673
Python Executable:  C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\u532246\\Desktop\\django-master-terbaru-4\\django-master-terbaru3\\django-master-terbaru3\\Django-master',
 'C:\\Users\\u532246\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\u532246\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\u532246\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\u532246\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38',
 'C:\\Users\\u532246\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 7 Jan 2020 09:38:09 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\u532246\Desktop\django-master-terbaru-4\django-master-terbaru3\django-master-terbaru3\Django-master\polls\templates\manage_user.html, error at line 342

Reverse for 'deleteuser' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['deleteuseradmin/(?P<user_name>[^/]+)$']
332           }
333         });
334       });
335       });
336   </script>
337   <script>
338 
339 function myFunction() {
340   var txt;
341   if (confirm("Do you want to delete!")) {
342    window.location.href ='{% url 'polls:deleteuser' user.name %}';
343   } else {
344   //don't do anything
345   }
346 
347 }
348   </script>
349 
350 </body>
351 
352 </html>
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\u532246\Desktop\django-master-terbaru-4\django-master-terbaru3\django-master-terbaru3\Django-master\polls\views.py in manageuser
            return render(request, 'manage_user.html',context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py in render
            return self.template.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                    return self._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render
            url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\u532246\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix
        raise NoReverseMatch(msg) …
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: Paste your `views` code for delete. Also in the mean time read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView

Comment: @bmons  if user.username it will delete the user who delete the user right?

Comment: try this `{% url 'polls:deleteuser' user.name %}`

Comment: @ans2human not working , because my url cannot take the parameter which i already set deleteuseradmin/<str:user_name> , when i put it in the button onclick = "window.location.href ='{% url 'polls:deleteuser' user_name=user.name %}';" , it perfectly fine , but when i start to put it to the script it cannot detect the "user_name"

Comment: The `del_user` view isn't relevant here since it isn't even called as far as I can see. We need to see the view that renders the javascript snippet you're showing. The error tells you that `user.name` is empty.

Comment: I think user.name in URL is blank

Comment: @dirkgroten i call the value in window.location.href ='{% url 'polls:deleteuser' user_name=user.name %}'; (if im not mistaking ur statement) , polls:deleteuser reffering to the del_user in the path.py

Comment: @c.grey yep , but it wont error if i just straight <td>                  
                       <button  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick = "window.location.href ='{% url 'polls:deleteuser' user_name=user.name %}';"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></button>
                    </td> . it wont error but no confirmation

Comment: @trytocode I meant the **view** that renders your javascript. As I said, the error means `user` is not defined or `user.name` is not defined or empty. So please check the context that your view is passing to the template.

Comment: Also I'm not sure I understand what exactly is happening. You say you click on the button, the confirmation pop-up is shown and when you click ok, the error is shown?  Can you show the full error trace please?

Comment: @dirkgroten i want to make delete with confirmation , first of all i make without a confirmation pop up ,  and it works with <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick = "window.location.href ='{% url 'polls:deleteuser' user_name=user.name %}';"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></button> </td>  , then i try to use popup button , but the page isnt load , because there is error in the script , i cannot use  window.location.href ='{% url 'polls:deleteuser' user_name=user.name %}' because the user_name not found , thats why

Comment: The error tells you that everything works fine. The last step in your view is `redirect('/manageuser') and the error is when calling "/manageuser" URL. So all the code you're showing here is actually working. The problem is with the view for "/manageuser".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205508/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-trytocode).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<button  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="myFunction({{user.name}})"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></button>

function myFunction(user_name) {
  var txt;
  if (confirm("Do you want to delete!")) {
   window.location.href ='{% url 'polls:deleteuser' user_name='+user_name+' %}';
  } else {
  //don't do anything
  }

}
```

hope it helps

Comment: This answer makes no sense. The `{% url %}` template tag is evaluated by Django to build the javascript. So having `user_name='+user_name+'` will create this javascript: `window.location.href = '/polls/deleteuseradmin/+user_name+'`

Answer (score -1):

This is not the solution, but the steps to debug this issue:

1. Look at the HTML source code **in your browser** (not in your source editor), so you can see what the real javascript is that is executed, after Django renders the templates. That way you can check that the URL inside your javascript is correct.
2. Inside your browser debug tools, go to the Network tab and look at the requests/responses being made. You would see that:

   - When you click "ok", the request for /deleteuseradmin/ is made correctly (HTTP GET request)
   - There is a redirect (HTTP 302) response with Location header set to "/manageuser"
   - This is when the error occurs, returning a HTTP 404.
3. Inside your source editor (IDE), set a breakpoint in your `del_user` view. You'll see that you hit that breakpoint and are able to step through your code until the `redirect('/manageuser') call, so everything is working as expected.

The error says "NoReverseMatch at /manageuser/" so the problem is when fetching "/manageuser/".

Now you would need to look at the template rendered by "/manageuser" corresponding view. Does that template contain a `{% url 'polls:deleteuser' user_name=user.name %}'? Is`user` defined correctly?